# Isomorphism between Relative Homology Groups.

Tags: homology-cohomology

I am trying to prove the following statement.

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then show that the homology group of $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A)$ and $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - B)$ are isomorphic.

I tried using long exact sequence for pairs twice. I got

$$\dots \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)\to \dots$$
and
$$\dots \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B)\to \dots$$

I tried to use the following diagram.

\begin{matrix}
 \dots \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n} - A)& \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n}) &\to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A)  &\to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)\to \dots \\ 
 \downarrow & \downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\
 \dots \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n} - B)& \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n}) &\to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - B)  &\to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B) \to \dots 
\end{matrix}

I thought diagram chasing would help, but it doesn't as I am not getting any vertical maps.

---

Can anyone help me with this problem. I read few answers but I cannot use Alexander's Duality. Thank you.

---

Edit 1

As RJP suggested, I got

> $ \dots \to 0 \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)\to 0 \to \dots $ is exact implies $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)$ and simmilarly $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B)$.

Now how do I show that $H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B)$?

Note- I tried and refered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121316/if-a-and-b-are-homeomorphic-proper-closed-subsets-of-mathbbrn-do-thei)

But it didn't help. Can anyone give a simpler reasoning?

Comment: If I remind you that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, does that help you? (Hint:  use the two long exact sequences seperately)

Comment: What are the vertical maps in your diagram?

Comment: @Thorgott, I am looking for that. I do not know which vertical maps will help me. I am unable to find any suitable map which will help. That is why I am here

Comment: @RJP, So $ \dots \to 0 \to H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \to H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)\to 0 \to \dots $ is exact implies $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - A) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A)$ and simmilarly $H_i(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B)$. Now how do I show that $H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -A) \cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} -B)$?