# Computing Cohomology of Genus 2 Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm confused by one part of Proposition 28.5 (Introduction to Manifolds, 2), which provides the cohomology of the genus 2 surface.

> [image]

1. What exact are the open sets $U$ and $V$? I thought they were tori, because the chart shows that $ H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \oplus \mathbb{R}^2 $. But then it has $H^2(U) \oplus H^2(V) = 0$, while $H^2(T^2) = \mathbb R$.
2. In general, what is the cohomology of a torus with a side chopped off (like in Fig 28.4 below) is?
3. Relatedly, is it generally the case that $H^k(U \sqcup V) = H^k(U) \oplus H^k(V)? $ In the former, we've cut out the intersection, so I don't see how it would have the same cohomology as the latter.

Comment: 1. They are exactly drawn in the diagram; they're punctured tori. 2. Show that the punctured torus deformation retracts onto a wedge of two circles. 3. Yes.

Comment: I'm confused by your response to (2). $U$ appears to be something like $\Sigma_2 - \overline{B}$, where $\overline{B}$ is a closed ball in $\Sigma_2$ that effectively cuts it in half. Where is the puncture? I know that a point is homotopic to a open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I still don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a little sloppy. They are tori with discs cut out, which are homotopy equivalent to and hence have the same cohomology as punctured tori.

Comment: Isn't your claim that $T^2 - D \simeq T^2 - \{p\}$ contradicted by this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897660/homotopy-type-of-the-complement-of-a-subspace)? In particular, $\{p\} \ncong D$, and both are plane continua.

Comment: Here's the theorem I'm referring to: *Two plane continua have the same shape if and only if their complements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic*.

Comment: There are two distinct issues with the argument you're trying to make here. 1) $T^2$ is not the plane. 2) A point and a disc have the same shape.

Comment: Did you mean an open disc? Yes I understand that a point and open disc have the same shape. But a torus with open disc removed isn't open.